# assets left behind after assetic:dump after editing config.yml

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, assetic

i am using the braincrafted bootstrap bundle, i had initially ran assetic:dump like it says in the setup instructions, then i altered the config.yml to use bootstrap subdir

```
braincrafted_bootstrap:
    output_dir: bootstrap  # web/bootstrap/(css|js)
```

after i ran assetic:dump again, the files old files are still left in web/css and web/js, and the new files are now in /web/bootstrap/js and /web/bootstrap/css

do i have to manage this directory manually at times like this, if so, whats the use of assetic:dump?

when i make configuration changes, how to do i know when to remove old folders and files, when my time is spent paying more attention to the /src directory as opposed to the mainly hands-free /web directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Assetic never deletes files. This is true for directories, but also for files.

I believe the reason is that Assetic has no history, that is, Assetic only knows about the current set of assets and not what assets where managed by Assetic in the past. The developers of Assetic probably made the call to not delete any assets since it would be worse to delete assets that should not be deleted than to not delete assets that should be deleted.

If you manage all your assets using Assetic (or use `assets:install`) you can manually delete the `css` and `js` folder when you delete or rename assets in the Assetic configuration and afterwards run `assetic:dump` and/or `assets:install`.